# jQuery get function

Tags: jquery, replace, get

i want to read an html file by using jquery get function, replace some characters then display result. I wrote get function and can replace the text. There are many rows in the table. All data inside rows displayed as text. Rows are ended with space; so iwant to replace "  ;" characters for every row. But the code below just replace the characters for the first row. How can i replace all "  ;" characters for all rows?

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://url',
            type: 'GET',
            success: function(data) {
            var def = $(data).find('tbody#div.divWord').html();

                $('#def').append('<p><b>' + word + '</b>:' + def + '</p>');

                $("div").each(function() {
                    var text = $(this).text();
                    text = text.replace("  ;", "@");
                    $(this).text(text);
                });

            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('error'); 
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the Replace function only matches the first result by default.

If you want to replace every occurence, you have to take a regular expression and set the "global flag":

```
text = text.replace(/ ;/g, "@");
```

or

```
text = text.replace(/\s;/g, "@");
```

where `\s` matches Whitespace Characters.

or

```
text = text.replace(new RegExp(" ;","g"),"@");
```

Comment: I couldn't replace space characters. I used RegExp(" ;","g"),"@") but not working. When i use RegExp(";","g"),"@") it works.

Comment: I guess `"\s;"` will do the job.

Comment: text.replace(/\s\s;/g, '@'); is OK

Comment: @Oktay if you want to replace several (in your case 2) whitespaces, you'd better write: `/\s{2};/`. `{x}` indicates the number of characters you want to match. Else you will mess up your code inceredibly fast, since reg-exp are hard to read.

Answer (score 1):

```
text = text.replace("  ;", "@"); -> text = text.replace(/  ;/g, "@");
```

Comment: It really helps, if you add a short explanation... ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use a regular expression in the replace, so that you can specify the global (g) flag:

```
text = text.replace(/  ;/g, "@");
```